# How can I group my CSV's list of dates into their Months?

Tags: python, pandas, csv, date, matplotlib

I have a CSV file which contains two columns, the first is a date column in the format 01/01/2020 and the second is a number for each month representing the months sales volume. The dates range from 2004 to 2019 and my task is to create a 12 bar chart, with each bar representing the average sales volume for that month across every years data. I attempted to use a groupby function but got an error relating to not having numeric types to aggregate. I am very new to python so apologies for the beginner questions. I Have posted my code so far below. Thanks in advance for any help with this :)

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import csv
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

file = "GlasgowSalesVolume.csv"

data = pd.read_csv(file)

typemean = (data.groupby(['Date', 'SalesVolume'], as_index=False).mean().groupby('Date') 
['SalesVolume'].mean())


Output:
DataError: No numeric types to aggregate
```

enter code here

Comment: please provide sample input data and expected output

Comment: you probably simply can do `df.groupby(df.Date.month).mean()`

Comment: Ok sorry I'm actually not sure how to do that. My input data is just a csv with a date column in the described format and a sales value column with a numeric value such as 1000. I want to essentially create 12 new dataframes which each contain an average sales volume for that month. I'm then going to use that for a bar chart. Sorry again I don't know how to provide sample output in the comments. It was a mess

Comment: Sorry just saw your previous comment. Thank you, I will try it. Much appreciated

Comment: I get an error with that line : AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'month'. I think because the dates are just stored in the format 01/01/2004

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I prepared a DataFrame limited to just 2 rows and 3 months:

```
         Date  Sales
0  01/01/2019      3
1  01/02/2019      4
2  01/03/2019      8
3  01/01/2020     10
4  01/02/2020     20
5  01/03/2020     30
```

For now *Date* column is of *string* type, so the first step is to
convert it to *datetime64*:

```
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, dayfirst=True)
```

Now to compute your result, run:

```
result = df.groupby(df.Date.dt.month).Sales.mean()
```

The result is a *Series* containing:

```
Date
1     6.5
2    12.0
3    19.0
Name: Sales, dtype: float64
```

The index is the month number (*1* thru *12*) and the value is the mean from
respective month, from all years.